# Interpolation in Ionic 4 and angular

Tags: ionic4, angular8

I have an issue doing interpolation on `ionic 4` and `angular 8`.

My code:

```
<div style="background-color: lightgray;height: 40px;padding: 10px;"> **{{in_stock}}** products found</div>
```

Getting error:

> [console.error]: "ERROR" {}

Comment: Are you sure this is related to interpolation?

Comment: if in_stock is an attribute - apply attribute binding if property - property binding. **{{}}** is really something else that is not part of angular syntax